# How to make PS script run against each line of a csv?

Tags: powershell

I currently have a PS script that is used for remediation of breached user accounts in a hybrid O365/On-prem AD environment.  The script currently works as intended, enabling MFA, logging, resetting passwords, removing mailbox rules, etc.

There are times when we must remediate more than just a few accounts.  That being said I am trying to set up the script to go line by line in a CSV file with headers to pull the users UPN name and execute the script for each UPN name in a csv.

Currently the script cant take and run multiple inputs for each function at once time so the script would need to re-run again.  Additionally, the script pulls cmdlets and etc for each time it runs, being able to speed up the script by say keeping the initial session open would be a bonus.

Ideally, the result would be the script continue to run without requiring me to enter another UPN.

Comment: Could you provide a  csv file with headers and sample data?

Comment: I dont have one generated at this time but it would be simple.  Only need to pull data from a single column.  The header may be something like "UPN" and the data may be first.last@domain.com

Comment: Ok, so there is only one field in the csv.

Comment: Yes, for this instance there will only be a single column.

Comment: Can you please provide the command you use to run the script? It should be easy enough to wrap it in a `foreach` command and replace the UPN with a variable

Comment: @Shadowzee typically running the script is simply .\remediateaccount.ps1 -upn *upn*  I can provide the script as well if you would like.

Comment: @AndrewDiaz yes please post your code

Comment: @trebleCode https://pastebin.com/hggUm4Bu

Comment: @AndrewDiaz can't view Pastebin on a restricted machine. Can you post your code in this post?